# "No target" in "no project" issue in code::blocks

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

Whenever I compile a source code in code::blocks, I encounter an error which tells me this:

> Build file: "no target" in "no project"  (compiler: unknown)

Below is a link showing the image of a code where I am encountering this issue

[compilation problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrDJw.png)

THE COMPILER I AM USING IS THE GNU GCC COMPILER.

**How do I solve this issue?**

**For the above code I hadn't created a project.**

**But when I do create a project I encounter this message:**

> debug in train (compiler: GNU GCC COMPILER)

I am also attaching an image of the code showing this message

[compilation problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hTGW.png)

here are the contents of the build log tab
[build log tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ag2g.png)

Comment: What is in the "Build log" tab?

Comment: Did you create a project in codeblocks or just open some c++ files and try to build?

Comment: @drescherjm I created the source code in codeblocks

Comment: @KaranMehta With respect that doesn't answer the question. Did you create a **project** in code blocks? If you don't understand what that means then probably you didn't and you need to read the codeblocks documentation to understand how to use it to write C++ programs.

Comment: @john I have edited my question, I hadn't created a project for that code shown but when I do create a project then an error still persists which I have highlighted in my question by editing it.

Comment: Solve it by creating a project. Having a project is a requirement for many IDEs.

Comment: Sorry but "debug in train" is not an error message. "train" is the name of the folder where you put your code. Sorry but we can't teach you how to use code blocks, you have to learn how to use it yourself, or from someone who can help you face to face, or follow a guide on the internet.

Comment: Again, can you please post the contents of "Build log" tab? It's at the bottom, near the "Build messages" one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i have edited my answer and have pasted the image of the build log tab

Comment: The compiler seems to be broken? Codeblocks comes with an outdated compiler anyway, try installing the latest [MinGW-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download).

Answer (score 1):

You could change some of the project settings but I think It'd be easier if you start from the beginning.
Run code blocks and then click create new project -> console application and choose the name and the path of it.
It seems like you've just created the cpp file and opened it in code blocks.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I did not create a project but when I do create a project an error still persists which I have highlighted in my question by editing it, please have a look.

Comment: I assume you have installed code blocks recently. Could you provide the screenshot of what version of installer you have chosen (on the website of code blocks)?

Comment: If you're on windows, you should've chosen binary release -> codeblocks-17.12mingw-setup.exe
If you have chosen something else, try to uninstall current version and install the one I have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Search for the file "guimain.exe" and run.

It should be in the "libexec \ mingw-get \ guimain.exe" directory

Choose to include the "mingw32-gcc-g ++ - bin" package and install this, it will work.

I had the same problem and found that this g ++ does not install installed via mingw.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMszK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Settings -> Compiler -> Toolchain executables shows the right compiler. Clicking on auto-detect seems to work.
Then create a new project of type Console App (as suggested already). After the project is created, go to the left menu and click on your project, go to Source, and open main.And then delete the "Hello World" code already there and copy/paste in your source.
I did these steps and then Build and Run worked just fine.